# EL expression can access the son of son object in scope?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, el

Can I use EL expression like this ? Topic comes from a requestScope param that is List.

```
${topic.person.username}
```

Taking that Topic has a Person and Person has username. I am getting an error telling me that

```
Property 'username' not found on type br.com.gsc.model.tableMapping.User
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work fine. The error is just telling that `${topic.person}` returns an instance of the `br.com.gsc.model.tableMapping.User` class which in turn doesn't have a `public String getUsername()` method. One of those two facts is probably not what you expect. Fix the code accordingly. Perhaps it has to be a different type or the method is indeed missing/incorrect?

Comment: Just foung my mistake.... the username var has a getter with the name getUserName... and i was asking in the EL for username.

Comment: Yes, you'd need `userName` instead or rename the method to `getUsername()`.